# How to join DBRef objects in mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Hi I am having my first collection

```
    students 
{
 "name" : "abc"
 "class" : "1"
 "subjects" : DBRef("subjects","class1")
}
```

and my second collection

```
 subjects
{
 "_id" : "class1"
 "sub1" : "english"
 "sub2" : "physics"
}
```

I want to achieve my output as below my joining the above two collections

```
   {
 "name" : "abc"
 "class" : "1"
 "subjects" : {sub1 : "english",sub2 : "physics"}
}
```

Is it possible,if yes how?

Comment: I am just wondering whether the answer was helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@DBRef` to refer the `Subjects` document from `Student`.

> The mapping framework doesn't have to store child objects embedded
>   within the document. You can also store them separately and use a
>   DBRef to refer to that document. When the object is loaded from
>   MongoDB, those references will be eagerly resolved and you will get
>   back a mapped object that looks the same as if it had been stored
>   embedded within your master document.
>
> Here's an example of using a DBRef to refer to a specific document
>   that exists independently of the object in which it is referenced
>   (both classes are shown in-line for brevity's sake):

[Refer this link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html)

[Another SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211645/spring-data-mongo-how-to-query-by-dbref-fields-id)

**Edit:-**

Actually, to give you more details, the `@DBRef` annotation will eagerly load the data (i.e. Subjects in this case).

**Students model class:-**

```
@Document(collection = "students")
public class Students implements Serializable, BaseDocument {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3534650012619938612L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("class")
    private String className;

    @DBRef
    @Field("subjects")
    private Subject subject;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Students [id=" + id + ", className=" + className + ", subject=" + subject + "]";
    }
}
```

**Subjects model class:-**

```
@Document(collection = "subjects")
public class Subject implements Serializable, BaseDocument {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3534650012619938612L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String sub1;
    private String sub2;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSub1() {
        return sub1;
    }

    public String getSub2() {
        return sub2;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setSub1(String sub1) {
        this.sub1 = sub1;
    }

    public void setSub2(String sub2) {
        this.sub2 = sub2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Subject [id=" + id + ", sub1=" + sub1 + ", sub2=" + sub2 + "]";
    }

}
```

**Get Student by Id:-**

When you get students by Id, the framework/mongodb will automatically load the subject data. You don't need to specifically do join to get the subject data.

```
public Students getStudents(String id) {

        MongoOperations mongoOperations = getMongoConnection();

        Students students = mongoOperations.findById(id, Students.class);

        System.out.println(students.toString());

        return students;

    }
```

**Output:-**

```
Students [id=584ea66e9e53b7802651de36, className=1, subject=Subject [id=class1, sub1=english, sub2=physics]]
```

**Subjects collection:-**

```
{
    "_id" : "class1",
    "sub1" : "english",
    "sub2" : "physics"
}
```

**Students collection:-**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584ea66e9e53b7802651de36"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "class" : "1",
    "subjects" : {
        "$ref" : "subjects",
        "$id" : "class1",
        "$db" : "localhost"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your links. But I want to perform join to combine data. Is it possible?

Comment: When you get students, you will get subjects object. I hope that is what you are expecting. As mentioned in API doc, it will be eagerly loaded. I have used it before.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your student collection like this:

```
    students 
{
 "name" : "abc"
 "class" : "1"
 "subjects" : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}] // You will store Objectids of subject
}
```

Now when you do find query on student then populate the data.

Comment: sorry,since i am very new to this can u please explain in detail.